# Timezone looping issues in php

Tags: php, mysql, loops, timezone

The code below creates a loop, sorts the loop based on time, and then echos the results of that loop until there is no more time left to loop, then it stops.

The code works great, except I cannot seem to adjust the times based on user timezone. When I try, it seems to only display 1 result, then the loop stops.

```
while ( $row = $stmt->fetch() ) 
{
    if (!($sc > $stopcount)) 
    {
        $i++;
        if( date('M d, Y', strtotime($row['time'])) !== $lastTime )
        { 
            if ($i == '1') 
            { 
                    echo '</tr><tr><td colspan="6" class="heading">'. date('M d, Y', strtotime($row['time'])) .'</td></tr>';
            } else if ( $lastTime === NULL ) 
            {
            echo '</tr>'; 
            } else 
            { echo '</tr><tr><td colspan="6" class="heading">'. date('M d, Y', strtotime($row['time'])) .'</td></tr>'; 
            }
            $lastTime = date('M d, Y', strtotime($row['time']));
        } if ($i >= $sc) 
        { ?>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" value="<? echo $row['id']; ?>" />
                </td>
                <td class="status">
                    <? if ($row['status'] == 'unopened' || $row['status'] == 'closed') { ?> 
                        <span id="<? echo $row['id']; ?>" class="icon-folder-close"></span> 
                    <? } ?>
                    <? if ($row['status'] == 'opened' || $row['status'] == 'reopened') { ?> 
                        <span class="icon-folder-open"></span> 
                    <? } ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <? echo $row['mailfrom']; ?>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <strong><a href="#preview_mail" class="mails_show open" id="<? echo $row['id']; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-show="mail-<? echo $i; ?>"><? echo $row['subject']; ?></a></strong>
                    <div id="mail-<? echo $i; ?>" class="mails_container">
                        <div class="from"><? echo $row['mailfrom']; ?></div>
                        <div class="to"><? echo $row['mailto']; ?></div>
                        <div class="ids"><? echo $row['id']; ?></div>
                        <div class="key"><? echo $row['pin']; ?></div>
                        <div class="subject"><? echo $row['subject']; ?></div>
                        <div class="attach"><? if ($row['attachment'] !== NULL) { ?> <span class="icon-gift"></span> <a href="<? echo $row['attachment']; ?>"><? echo $row['attachment']; ?></a> <? } else { ?><span class="icon-none"></span>NONE<? } ?></div>
                        <div class="body">
                            <p><? echo $row['message']; ?></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="body_reply">
                            <p><? echo $row['message']; ?></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>                                    
                </td>
                <td>
                    <?
                    $tttime = $row['time'];
                    $ttime = new DateTime($tttime);
                    $stmt=$db->prepare('SELECT timezone FROM member_credits WHERE username = :user');
                    $stmt->bindParam(':user', $username);
                    $stmt->execute();
                    $row1 = $stmt->fetch();
                    $usersTimezone = (new DateTimeZone($row1[timezone]));
                    $ttime->setTimeZone($usersTimezone);
                    $ttimee = $ttime->format('h:i, A');
                    ?>
                    <? echo $ttimee; ?>
                </td>
                <td style="padding: 10px 10px !important;">
                    <? if (isset($row[attachment])) { ?>
                        <span style="margin-left: 0 !important;" class="icon-gift"></span>
                    <? $bytes=filesize($row[attachment]); echo formatSizeUnits($bytes); } else {?> <? } ?>
                </td>
            </tr>
        <? $sc++;
        }  
    }
}
?>
```

To make this perfectly clear, if I remove the timezone formatting code below from the code above, the loop runs perfectly. If I keep the timezone code from below, it only displays one result and breaks the loop.

```
    $ttime = new DateTime($tttime);

    $stmt=$db->prepare('SELECT timezone FROM member_credits WHERE username = :user');
    $stmt->bindParam(':user', $username);
    $stmt->execute();
    $row1 = $stmt->fetch();

    $usersTimezone = (new DateTimeZone($row1[timezone]));
    $ttime->setTimeZone($usersTimezone);
    $ttimee = $ttime->format('h:i, A');
```

What am I doing wrong? How can I write this in such a way that the time is sorted based on the full server date/time stored in the database, then echo'd based on just the time in 12 hour format without date, converted from users timezone settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well this took me some serious amount of time to work through.

The problem was as follows:

I have a while loop

```
while ( $row = $stmt->fetch() )
```

This means if I set $row to something other than $stmt->fetch(), the while loop will end. I knew that from the start, hence calling the second $row1.

What I wasn't also realizing is that means if I used $stmt to perform other functions within the while loop, it to would break the while loop.

The solution was simply to use a different variable in the time functions.

```
    $ttime = new DateTime($tttime);

    $stmt2=$db->prepare('SELECT timezone FROM member_credits WHERE username = :user');
    $stmt2->bindParam(':user', $username);
    $stmt2->execute();
    $row1 = $stmt2->fetch();

    $usersTimezone = (new DateTimeZone($row1[timezone]));
    $ttime->setTimeZone($usersTimezone);
    $ttimee = $ttime->format('h:i, A');
```